# Does Tumblr ever show adverts on your blog?

Tags: tumblr

If I create a blog on Tumblr will they display ads on the public pages of my site?

(For context I'm coming from WordPress.com which sometimes does show ads and they have a paid option to remove them.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope, tumblr as a service will not automatically put ads on your page, but you can always ad them in yourself via their 'additional html' box or if you create your own theme you could put the code for ads in there too.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Just out of interest, does anyone know what Tumblrs business model is if they're not putting ads on blogs and also don't seem to have any premium features?

Comment: In answer to my own comment it seems that at the moment it's selling premium themes. Other options will be developed in the future (plenty of VC money at the moment).  Some commentators have wondered about the options available to them - e.g. [this one](http://www.bnet.com/blog/technology-business/another-look-at-tumblr-more-users-but-its-business-model-is-still-iffy/6978).

Comment: Just FYI: a new feature you have to pay for: highlighting own posts in the dashboard of followers.

Answer (score -1):

Yes. Tumblr will not automatically place adds but you can put the adsense code and they will be shown on your blog.

Comment: I do not think the author was asking how to insert ads but whether ads will be placed on a tumblr.com blog.